# Java: How do I sort an ArrayList according to a natural ordering?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of instances of a class I created, each of which contains a single field with a String. I have implemented Comparable in the class I created. How do I sort the Array List?

Comment: You could just add your objects to a `SortedSet` such as a `TreeSet` and the collection will keep them sorted.

Answer (score 7):

[Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

**edit**
No errors for me

```
class Gene {
}
class MyGene extends Gene implements Comparable<MyGene> {
    public int compareTo(MyGene o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method is not implemented yet.");
    }
}
```

...

```
    List<MyGene> l = new ArrayList<MyGene>();
    Collections.sort(l);
```

Comment: That seems like it ought to work, except Eclipse complains that, "the inferred type [myClass] is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter<T extends comparable<? super T>>"

Comment: @Trevor You should define class like _class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>_  It will tell compiler that MyClass can be compared only with other MyClass instances.

Comment: I do have MyClass implementing MyClass in that way currently.

Comment: @Trevor Can you post its declaration, then?

Comment: public final class MyGene extends Gene implements Comparable<Gene> {

Comment: @Trevor try _Comparable<MyGene>_

Comment: The same complaint from Eclipse comes up when I change it to MyGene.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Java 8 API:

```
List<MyGene> l = new ArrayList<MyGene>();
l.stream().sorted().collect(toList());
```

Typically, you'd use something like that:

```
 List<MyGene> l = new ArrayList<MyGene>();
 l.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.getId().compareTo(o1.getId())).collect(toList());
```

, 
but since your MyGene already implements comparable, simple `sorted()` should suffice.